# Why does 'route print' print interfaces as IPs?

Tags: windows, networking

Output of `route print` on my Windows XP machine:

```
>route print
...
Network address       Network Mask          Gateway       Interface   Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0     37.44.40.247    37.44.40.247       1
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0   172.31.103.254   172.31.102.43       21
...
```

What is the logic of notation of interface as IP? What is the relation between them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are basically three ways to identify a network interface: Vendor ID, MAC address, and IP address. Only the IP address has any kind of *semantic* meaning in the context of a network route. "Broadcom NetXtreme Gigabit Ethernet" (Vendor ID) or 00-1C-C5-33-21-52 (MAC address) wouldn't be any more helpful, would they?

Comment: And of course you can normally find the corresponding `Description` and `Physical Address` (MAC address) in the list displayed by `ipconfig /all`.

Comment: So what is the relation? Why exactly `37.44.40.247` in my table?

Comment: @Lescott: Uh, ok... so you don't know how IP addresses are formed *at all*? That's a quite different subject, and you should probably ask a new question for it. No, wait... first check out "DHCP", ok? In one line, there is no deterministic logic behind it, IP addresses are somewhat random (within a specific range).

Comment: @Lescott The IP address is the address assigned to the interface, whether manually or automatically (e.g. DHCP). The interface can be (for example) a virtual or physical network card.

Comment: Check out my answer to this question: http://superuser.com/questions/206431/ethernet-vs-tcp-vs-ip/449730#449730